# C# sha256 to be used in Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

Blazor WASM no longer supports System.Security.Cryptography, I need a sha hash for my application.  I am mainly using it for a PRNG.  The reason I am using sha for PRNG is that it is portable. The old version of this used Python 2.x to generate a random number which is different than the pRND in Python 3.x.  The requirement is to have a PRNG that is available across systems and languages. The sha seems to fit that requirement, but since it has been removed from Blazor.

Any suggests.

Comment: Look [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/sha256managed.cs).

Comment: Here's the topic stating why it's not available and that there are no workarounds for System.Security.Cryptography https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/cryptography/5.0/cryptography-apis-not-supported-on-blazor-webassembly

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not sure why you're linking to the .NET Framework 4.8 source for System.Security.Crptography.SHA256Managed given that Blazor WASM is part of ASP.NET Core and won't run on .NET Framework

Comment: It doesn't matter.  The code is not platform-specific.  You may have to modify it a bit to suit your purposes.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not suggesting that you link to the .NET Framework 4.8.  I'm suggesting that you take that code and use it to make your PRNG.  The license for that code can be found [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html).

Comment: sha256 does not apply the TLS 1.3.  See following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng: Shouldn't be applicable, if the only purpose is to create a PRNG.  Of course, the begged question now becomes "What is the PRNG being used for?"

Comment: PRNG should be secure and the reason SHA is no longer being used by TLS 1.3 is the security of SHA is vulnerable.

Comment: The PRNG is used for selecting questions from a pool for a ham radio test.  It doesn't need to be cryptography secure or secure at all.  I am not using .NET 4.X or TLS.  I think Robert Harvey solution is the best.

Comment: I spoke too soon about Robert's solution.  It seems to be more C than C#.  Henk link pointed me to subtleCrypto but couldn't find any digest methods.

Comment: It is C#.  The "C" code you refer to is actually `unsafe` C# code, probably there for performance reasons.